# Overriding a function argument in PHP:date()

Tags: php, date

I have a date formatted in this date("Y-m-d") and I want to over-ride all formats  of the date("y-m-d") to date("m.d.y").I need to do this like these

echo date('y-d-m');
//but still result to 11-12-09
?>

How to over-ride the date("y-m-d") to date("m.d.y").Coz My scripts has a lot of date();

Answer (score 1):

That... is not something you can really do in PHP. Instead, you're probably going to have to swap the calls to `date()` manually (and perhaps define a constant to use as the date format string for the future instead of hardcoded strings, so that if you want to change them all again in the future, it's easier?

Comment: So that's easier.Yah I am currently using constant by now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd better to right a helper and which itself calls php's date function, and use that instead